# Using YAML to replace smaller SQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, yaml

`Symfony` has turned me on to the power of [YAML](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/yaml.html). It used to be default for me to use MySQL to make tables for an ecommerce site of say `supported_countries`,`units_of_measure` or `sku_conditions`. But now, I might prefer using `YAML` to create a `config/countries.yml`, `config/units.yml` or `config/skuConditions.yml`. So I'm curious -- in situations like this are there an significant performance factors to consider when deciding to **parse and analyzing a YAML file ~ vs ~ Querying and Analyzing SQL data?**

### countries.yml

```
US:
    code: US
    name: United States
CA: 
    code: CA
    name: Canada
```

### skuConditions.yml

```
default-unit: new
units
    new:
        short: new
        long: brand spanking new
        description: never been used.
    open-box:
        short: open
        long: pretty much new
        description: the box has been opened but never used.
```

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: The big problem I see with this so far is finding a good location for the .yml file. You really don't want the .yml files to be in the main bundle because that would limit portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think YAML is very suitable for configuration files, that's the way Symfony uses it, but if your data is changing a lot, you need a database. If you are worried about performance think using a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

Comment: In situations where the data is not quite configuration and doesn't change a lot? Such as my example of skuConditions, there might only be data points and they'd never change.

Comment: Ok, in this situation a YAML file is appropiate